# How to skip invalid rows and ignore UnknowValues in Apache Beam big query api

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

In Apache engine I am able to skip invalidrows and unknown values using below code

```
.setSkipInvalidRows(true).setIgnoreUnknownValues(true)
```

Now I am migrating to dataflow (Apachebeam 2.2). Is there any way to skip the invalid rows and unknown values as above?

Thanks,
Damodar Allareddy

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been added in

https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/6e8398010a2001e0528e636730e373260be6b813

although its not in 2.6 (current release as of august 2018) I expect it to be in 2.7 whenever that is released